# Getting latest sandcastle off the ground

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sandcastle

The download page for sandcastle is [here](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/releases/view/47665). Downloading the MSI and installing it produces a directory in program files (x86), but no menu items in start and no 'getting started'. A review comment claims that the solution is to also download the source archive and find an MSI in there, but I don't see any MSIs inside the source archive. What's the procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/), which is a GUI for Sandcastle (similar to NDoc). Sandcastle without this is hardly operable, and it's definetely not worth trying.

HTH.
Thomas

Comment: SHFB has moved to a new location: https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/releases as codeplex was closed quite a while ago, also check the github pages for more information: https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB